# Resetting variables and async programming in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis, socket.io

I am playing around with async programming in nodeJS and ran into an interesting problem.

I have something like this in my code:

```
// require modules
var clientDetails = {}; // Initialize the object at the top of the file.

io.use(authenticate) // a method which gets some user information from the database and assigns the socket ID to the user. clientDetails object gets the data here.

io.on('connection', socketIOConnection); // A method which calls some methods using promises to control the flow of the method calls and socket.on('disconnect') event.
redisClient.on('message', redisMessage); // An event for redis pub/sub 

function socketIOConnection(socket) {
    // a few method chain calls to control the async flow
    storeUserDetailsToRedis().then().then().then().then() 
    socket.on('disconnect', socketIODisconnect)

}

function socketIODisconnect() {
  // a few chain calls to control the async flow. 
  removeUserDetailsToRedis().then().then().then().then()
}
```

I am looking for a way to clear the client details object after the socket IO Connection (or disconnect) event ends. Or with other words all of the promises are resolved.

Currently, if I try to normally do clientDetails = {}, it will be executed first and the app will fail / have undefined data.

I need to clear the clientDetails object so I can have a fresh object on every page refresh. Without clearing, it still holds old data and messes up my redis user information data stored there.

I am using socket IO and Redis in this project.

Does anyone have any idea how to empty the clientDetails object while maintaining async control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. I added the clientDetails object on the socket itself instead of having it as a variable at the top of the file. Now I have access to all of the events, but I had to add it as a parameter to all my methods.